# Is using .se, Sweden's top level domain name, a bad idea for a website hosted in the United States

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I have a client with a website name that ends with se. I thought instead of dealing with .com domain names I would register something like gardenho.se.

Is there anything wrong with this? Does this impact SEO? Can I simply have the one name and then redirect it to the .com domain name so that it can be used on business cards?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with it at all. Keep in mind that http://gardenho.se won't show up as 'garden hose' to Google. You can use a 301 to redirect the .com